# What to do when a question can be answered with the answer to another question?

Tags: support

There are cases where a answer of another question does not answer a question OP asks directly, but solves it in a better way. What should be done in such a case? Here are some options I can think of:

- The answer to the other question be copy pasted with a link to it, to net some rep in the process.
- The question be marked as a duplciate of that answer.
- A comment linking to the other question.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355767/python-2-7-subprocess-check-output-statement-opens-and-closes-a-windows-comman/26355896) is an example of what I mean.

Comment: I would close it as duplicate and instead of the automatic comment add a link to the answer in the other question

Comment: _"to net some rep in the process."_ is (basically) never a valid reason to do something on SO.

Comment: @Cerbrus You're right, but rep has always been at the core of the SO gaming process, and one of the incentives to participate regularly. Let's just not be surprised when people do something to gain rep in the process...

Comment: I've edited the title because "duplicate answer" is an ambiguous term. It could refer to a case where there is a single question on which two answers are duplicate of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If another question has the answer then you should be marking the question as a duplicate, or add a comment linking the two questions - depending on how close the duplication is.

You should definitely **not** be copying the other answer.

Comment: It seems that this is about another question about a similar problem, but still a different question. The fact that an answer can solve two distinct questions doesn't mean those questions are duplicates. Here, the two questions aim to achieve the same overall goal, but they are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 0):

This particular example is not a duplicate question at all, it's a case of "*I don't necessarily know how to answer your question, but it's clear from your example what you're trying to achieve, and here is another, better way*".

Effectively, the answer doesn't actually answer the question.

Personally, I don't mind such an answer, since it's clearly on topic for the overall problem asked, and may help other users reading the page if they have the same problem, with the same example.

(It only becomes a problem if someone edits the question to try to make it more general, removing that particular example, in which case the answer would make sense at all.)

Two problems having similar solutions doesn't mean that the two problems are the same.

Comment: Ah - in that case the other answer should be either linked to or *perhaps* copied **and modified** with attribution.

Comment: @ChrisF The attribution is not done perfectly here, but it's at least linked correctly to be fair (so I don't think there was any attempt of cheating).